# MediaRecorder on Firefox 53.0.2 does not support audio recording

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, web-mediarecorder

I have an issue with the MediaRecorder API. It works fine on Chrome and used to work on earlier versions of Firefox (Mac), but since version 53.0.2, I get the following in the dev console:

`--> MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm')
false
--> MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm')
true`

Did Firefox stop supporting audio recording through the MediaRecorder API?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox did implement `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported()` in FF47. I did an mozRegression loop between now and 47 to check when it did change as you said.

Result : It never reported true for `audio/webm` in any version tried (on osX).

But, Firefox does support `audio/ogg` mimeType, (*which I guess is the default for audio only*). And since both Firefox and Chrome do record audio encoded with an [Opus codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)), the more common mimeType for the container is indeed `audio/ogg`.

Note that Chrome doesn't return true for `audio/ogg`.

Looking forward for [this API](https://wicg.github.io/media-capabilities/).